# Automaticly log in on gmail from java

Tags: java, http

How can I send correct request with my login name and password from java? How request should look like?
I have to make it for my thesis and i dont know how do it. Could someone help me?

Comment: "I have to make it for my thesis"  Does that count as `homework`?  BTW the mind boggles that a candidate for a thesis needs to ask such basic & broad questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with GMail's IMAP interface which is well-supported in Java.

This tutorial may help http://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/

Information about IMAP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol

Other resources could be found by searching for 'gmail imap java' or similar.